# Import Error when running paho mqtt as root (sudo python3 filename.py)

Tags: python-3.x, mqtt, root, sudo, paho

I'm about to set up a Raspberry Pi 3+ Model A as a client for `openHAB2`. Here I have a sensor on the Pi and `WS2812b` (alias `Neopixel`) connected.

Now I wrote (my first script) in Python to publish the sensor data (Bosch BMP280) via paho mqtt to the broker. **This works as desired when I start the Python file with "python3 filename.py" ...**

If I want to start the **same file** with `"sudo python3 filename.py"` the following error message appears:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "mqtt_client.py", line 15, in <module>
     import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'
```

However, I would like to extend the script to use the WS2812b. To control the WS2812b, the script must be started with **root privileges**. So I do not understand why paho-mqtt is no longer known when running "sudo" ...

Does anyone have a solution for this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are running your script using `sudo python3 filename.py` it is using a python environment different from the one you used to install Paho.

In order to fix this you can either:

- Add `Defaults env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"` to your `/etc/sudoers`
- Run your script using `sudo /path/to/python pythonscript.py`

Comment: Hey. Thank you for this quick response. I'm still pretty new with the Pi and Python... What I have seen is that under both /home/pi/.local/lib and under /usr/lib the folder "python3.7" exists. Paho is under the former. Do you mean that with two different environments of Python? Unfortunately, I can not interpret /path/to/python correctly. Can you please formulate that more precisely?

What I have done so far is installed using sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt. Paho I find now at: /home/pi/.local/lib/Python3.7/site-packages

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. Just type `which python3` in your terminal and you'll get the desired path :)

Comment: @ben5en No problem :)